# Swedish Eurocard Credit Card

Tags: credit-card, sweden, charges

What are the currency conversion changes for Eurocard credit card issued in Sweden? The [official website](http://www.eurocard.se) is in Swedish and hard to navigate to locate this information.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to direct your inquiry to Eurocard to get specific information about the terms and conditions regarding the particular card you are interested in.

I navigated to their international website and searched for terms and conditions.

It appears the gold card has annual fees, 2% ATM withdraw fee (4.50 minimum) and a 2% currency conversion fee.
http://www.eurocardinternational.com/Corporate-solutions/For-cardholders/Eurocard-Corporate-Gold/Prices-terms-conditions/

The PDF of Terms and Conditions uses general verbiage about fees being the cardholders responsibility.
http://www.eurocardinternational.com/Global/International/PDF/Terms%20and%20conditions.pdf